# Grails. Incorrect values are assigned in variables from params

Tags: grails, groovy

When I try assigned value from params it now works incorrect.

```
System.out.println(params.test)   // I see 0
int test = params.test
System.out.println(test)   // I see 48
```

some my integer and float variables assigned value + 48

some boolean valiable all assigned true

I tried change grails version (2.3.7/2.3.4), rebuild project. But it works wrong.
May be I changed some settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is wrong here.

`params.test` has string value `0`

```
params.test = "0"
```

when it is type casted to `int` it's ascii value `48` gets assigned to `test`

```
assert 48 == (int)"0"
```

To get int value of string "0" from `params` you can use primitive methods applicable on `params`

```
params.int('test') // int 0
```

similarly for boolean

```
params.boolean('test') //boolean true/false
```

Comment: How I can send true value? I tried write int test = params.test as int. Its not worked too.

Comment: `params.boolean('test')` would give a boolean `true` if `test` has string `true`. See my update.

Comment: Refer [Simple Type Converters](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#typeConverters)

Comment: How is work with multi parameters? I use List test1 = params.list('test1') and List test2= params.list('test2') and in the loop assigned variables.